# profile guided optimization with Rcpp

Tags: gcc, rcpp

When trying to compile with flag I get the following error:

```
Error in dyn.load(dllfile) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/Projects/RBOrB/src/RBOrB.so':
  /home/Projects/RBOrB/src/RBOrB.so: undefined symbol: __gcov_merge_add
```

My Makevars looks like this:

```
CXXFLAGS += -O3 -march=native -fprofile-generate
PKG_CXXFLAGS += -O3 -std=c++11 -march=native -fprofile-generate
PKG_LIBS += $(shell ${R_HOME}/bin/Rscript -e "RcppParallel::RcppParallelLibs()") $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

Does R not support this or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

1. Use the same -std=c++11 in both CXXFLAGS and PKG_CXXFLAGS
2. A quick google suggests that -fprofile-generate needs corresponding linkage flags. Can you confirm that -fprofile-generate appears in the link command too?
3. Confirm that everything works correctly without profile flags.
4. From memory, I'm not sure that setting CXXFLAGS actually works. I believe your changes here may be overwritten.